# Does Collections.binarySearch() return the exact equal of key

Tags: java, collections

If I call `Collections.binarySearch(sortedList, key, compareMethod)`, is the item 'x' at the returned index (if the index is positive):

1.) the first value found for which `key = x` (as in key.equals(x))

or

2.) the first value found for which `compareMethod(key, x) == 0`

or

3.) neither of the above?

---

My specific problem:

I have a list `list` of `Point`s that each have an `(x,y)` coordinate pair. I sort the list in order of increasing `x` coordinate using a custom Comparator method `compareX()`.

`Point` equality (`Point.equals()`) is defined as identical `x` and `y` coordinates

Now, I want to `binarySearch` my list for `key`, so I call `Collections.binarySearch(list, key, compareX)` - if a `Point` is found, is it guaranteed to have `x = key.x` **and** `y = key.y`, or just `x = key.x`?

Comment: I have read your question a couple of times know, but I don't think I quite understand what you want to do. Why isn't the `Comparator` you're passing into `binarySearch()` comparing both x and y coordinates?

Comment: @MickMnemonic the list itself is sorted only by x coordinate - are you implying the only way to be sure of the outcome is to have the comparator compare by x coordinate **then by y coordinate**?

Comment: Yes, the JavaDoc and janos' answer should make this clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1.) the first value found for which key = x (as in key.equals(x)), or
>
> 2.) the first value found for which compareMethod(key, x) == 0, or

Neither, if there are multiple values for which `compareMethod(key, x) == 0`. It will return one of those values, but it's undetermined which one.
From the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch-java.util.List-T-):

> If the list contains multiple elements equal to the specified object, there is no guarantee which one will be found.

As for the other part of your question,
if `compareMethod` compares only `x`,
then the only guarantee you get is that `x = key.x`.

If you used a `compareMethod` that uses *consistent comparison logic* over both `x` and `y`, then you will be guaranteed to get `x = key.x` and `y = key.y`, if such point exists.
For example:

```
Comparator<Point> cmp = (p1, p2) -> {
  int cmpx = Integer.compare(p1.x, p2.x);
  if (cmpx != 0) {
    return cmpx;
  }
  return Integer.compare(p1.y, p2.y);
};
```

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "consistent comparison logic"?

Comment: @MyStackRunnethOver I updated my post, hope it's clearer. By consistent comparison logic, I mean that if `cmp(a, b) < 0` if and only if `a.x < b.x` or `a.x == b.x && a.y < b.y`, and using similar logic for `cmp(a, b) > 0`

Comment: @MyStackRunnethOver I added an example point-comparator implementation, if that helps.

Comment: I'm all set, thank you for your help - I appreciate all your clarifications

Answer (score -1):

The `binarySearch` method will test equality based on the `Comparator`, not based on `equals`.

The [Javadoc for Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) introduces the concept of a `Comparator` being consistent with `equals`; the two are consistent when `a.equals(b)` is the same as `a.compareTo(b) == 0` for all possible values of `a` and `b`.  `Comparator`s which are inconsistent with `equals` should should be used with caution, and avoided where possible.

Comment: _The binarySearch method will test equality based on the Comparator, not based on equals._ Do you have evidence?

Comment: @MyStackRunnethOver Will the source code do as evidence? [`Collections.binarySearch(List<? extends T> list, T key, Comparator<? super T> c)`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java#l374)

Comment: Logically, it's obvious that this is correct, but I'm surprised that it isn't clearly stated in the documentation.

Comment: @MyStackRunnethOver My evidence is the test that I wrote to confirm this answer before posting it.  While questions of clarification are certainly welcome, comments demanding that I show evidence of this are not helpful, and will at best result in the community declining to answer any future question of yours.

Comment: @JoeC I didn't mean to come off as offensive or unappreciative, but please understand that I had no reason to trust your assertion - without the test case or a link to supporting evidence, it doesn't help. So I don't think I was out of bounds in asking for proof - I could have said "can you clarify how you know 'the binarySearch method will test equality based on the Comparator, not based on equals'?" Regardless, evidence has been provided - thank you

Comment: Trust me when I say, when I post an answer that is incorrect, the SO Community lets me know pretty quickly :)

Comment: You're making an unsourced assertion here. I don't see the problem with asking for evidence. If you wrote a test, why not include it or at least mention it? Also, testing is relatively weak evidence, as a rule. Unspecified behavior can vary across versions, implementations or executions.

Answer (score -1):

Answering my own question here, to collect things said in different answers, and provide a clear explanation:

As evidenced in the `Collections.binarySearch()` [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java#l374), **all** comparisons are done using the Comparator method - so if `Compare(x,y) == 0`, `x` and `y` are considered equal.

Generally, this means that if `Collections.binarySearch()` returns a positive result, it will be the location of **some** value for which `Comparator` returns 0. If there is more than one such value, which one is undefined.

---

For my case specifically: as written in the question, the call to `Collections.binarySearch()` will return the index of some `Point` with `x = key.x`, if such a `Point` exists.

The correct solution is to update my `xCompare` method so that it compares `x` coordinates - if they are not equal, it returns that comparison. Otherwise, it compares `y` coordinates. This makes it so that the `Comparator` will compare first by `x` coordinate, and then (for any `Point`s with identical `x`) by `y` coordinate.

This will lead to a sort, and a search, first by `x`, then by `y`, where the comparison returns 0 if and only if both `x` and `y` are equal.